# call specific css keyframe animation on click without javascript

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a slider with navigation, without digging through javascript which i haven't learned yet. I set up a simpler example in the code and pen below. The idea is to use buttons in each div to trigger the correct keyframe animation.

https://codepen.io/sullamen/pen/pZrmaV

```
<div class="container">
<div class="container-item"><img src="#"> </div>
<div class="container-item"><img src="#"> </div>
<div class="container-item"><img src="#"> </div>
<div class="container-item"><img src="#"> </div>

.container {
display:flex;
width: 400vw;
}

.container-item{
width: 100vw;
transform: translateX(-100%);
}

@keyframes slide1-3{
0%{transform:translateX(-100%) }
25%{ transform:translateX(-100%) }
50% { transform:translateX(0%) }
75%{ transform:translateX(0%) }
100%{ transform:translateX(0%) }
}

@keyframes slide3-1{
0%{transform:translateX(0%) }
25%{ transform:translateX(0%) }
50% { transform:translateX(-100%) }
75%{ transform:translateX(-100%) }
100%{ transform:translateX(-100%) }
}


@keyframes slide1-2{ 
0%{transform:translateX(-100%) }
25%{ transform:translateX(-100%) }
50% { transform:translateX(-200%) }
75%{ transform:translateX(-200%) }
100%{ transform:translateX(-200%) }
}

@keyframes slide2-1{ 
0%{transform:translateX(-200%) }
25%{ transform:translateX(-200%) }
50% { transform:translateX(-100%) }
75%{ transform:translateX(-100%) }
100%{ transform:translateX(-100%) }
}

@keyframes slide2-3{
0%{transform:translateX(-200%) }
25%{ transform:translateX(-200%) }
50% { transform:translateX(-300%) }
75%{ transform:translateX(-300%) }
100%{ transform:translateX(-300%) }
}

@keyframes slide3-2{
0%{transform:translateX(-300%) }
25%{ transform:translateX(-300%) }
50% { transform:translateX(-200%) }
75%{ transform:translateX(-200%) }
100%{ transform:translateX(-200%) }
}
```

Comment: The only way to accomplish this without JavaScript would be some kind of HTML/CSS hack involving reacting to the `checked` state of checkboxes/radio buttons, which would be far more complicated than using JS to create a slider (which is something JS is pretty much necessary for).

Comment: I understand your approach "I don't know, I don't use", been there, respect. But I reccomend(If you have any basic experience with programming) to sit for one day and read basics. For simple actions like that JavaScript is easy and comfortable to use. Few lines of code instead of weird CSS tricks, which usually ain't combatible with every browser.

Answer (score 0):

I wish if there's a way to make a full slider in `css` but, unfortunately there isn't. So, if you really stuck with `css` the maximum you can do is create a button like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <button id="slider-goRight">&rarr;</button>
    <div class="container">
        <div>
            <img src="http://backgroundcheckall.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/background-1920x1080.jpg">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="https://wallpapermemory.com/uploads/403/abstract-space-background-1080p-194554.jpg">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="https://www.coinfeeds.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/wallpaper-254823.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And for the `css`:

```
.wrapper{
        width: 500px;
        height: auto;
        margin: auto;
        padding: 0px;
        position: relative;
        border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .wrapper button#slider-goLeft{
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        font-size: 30px;
        color: #000;
        background-color: #e6e5e5;
        border: 1px solid #919496;
        outline: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 10px;
        margin-top: -25px;
        cursor: pointer;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    .wrapper button#slider-goRight{
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        font-size: 30px;
        color: #000;
        background-color: #e6e5e5;
        border: 1px solid #919496;
        outline: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        right: 10px;
        margin-top: -25px;
        cursor: pointer;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    .wrapper .container{
        width: 1500px; /*500 * Number of images*/
        height: auto;
        margin: auto;
        padding: 0px;
        position: relative;
        left: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: all 1000ms linear 0ms;
    }
    .wrapper .container div{
        width: 500px;
        height: auto;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .wrapper .container div img{
        width: 100%;
    }

    /*Create button click events..*/

    .wrapper button#slider-goRight:active{
        opacity: .2;
    }
    .wrapper button#slider-goRight:active + div{
        left: -1000px;
    }
```

**Demo: [jsfiddle.net/wzrsmhxk/](https://jsfiddle.net/wzrsmhxk/)**

What I did is create a button `Active` event in `css` so while user pressing the button the container will slide and as soon as the user leave the button the container will back to it's original position.

this the only way to make slider with buttons in `css`.

> There's another option which it create a normal scroll.

Comment: that is pretty cool, but not exactly what I am going for. But i am gathering that JS is needed for what I want. Which I plan to learn soon.